# Alternative Idiom to "Horse's Mouth"

Tags: synonyms, idiom-requests

To be "straight from the horse's mouth" is to be from the most reliable source.

I am wanting a title like "The horse's mouth" for my newsletter but I don't really want to call myself a horse. What other idioms are there that I could use?

Comment: reliable source ?

Comment: *at first hand*?

Comment: ***Yours truly***.

Comment: @DanBron if you turn that into an answer, I'll accept. It's not quite the same sense but it works beautifully in the context.

Comment: @jcuenod ... done.

Comment: I used to live in a region with several seaports, and a newly built large bridge over a river estuary. The local newspaper used to run an editorial column called "View from the bridge", with reference to both the river bridge and ships' captains. Maybe there is the germ of an idea for you there.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A humorous way to refer to oneself in speech or writing, particularly when you want to emphasize your own situation or role, is ***yours truly***.

From *McGraw-Hill's Dictionary of American Slang and Colloquial Expressions*, for example:

> ***yours truly***:
>
> n. me, the speaker or writer.
>
> *If it was up to yours truly, there wouldn’t be any such problem.*

or from the *Cambridge Dictionary of American Idioms*:

> ***yours truly***
>
> me
>
> *Even though he never graduated from high school, his business ability rivaled anyone's, yours truly included.*
>
> *Some folks, such as yours truly, can't resist a clever pun or play on words.*
>
> **Usage notes**: usually used as a **humorous way of referring to yourself**

*Endangered Phrases* by Steven D. Price (2011) has a little more detail on its origins and register:

> ***yours truly***
>
> I.
>
> *For whatever reason of modesty (or false modesty) that prevented speakers or writers from using the first-person singular pronoun “I,” the “yours truly” convention was established. It came from the standard letter closing. It sounded mannered when it was first used in the 19th century and even more so now. Other equally stilted circumlocutions for “I” or “me” used in writing are “your reporter” (still found in alumni class notes) and “your correspondent.”*

All definitions located via [The Free Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/yours+truly).

Comment: Ha! I don't think I've ever had a accepted, but negative-scoring, answer before.

Comment: Happy to oblige.

Comment: I was about to upvote the answer, but decided to refrain from doing so ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try **[fountainhead](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/fountainhead)**

> An original source of something (Oxford)

If you're okay with calling yourself a fountain, that is.

Comment: Or, on that basis 'font of knowledge'

Answer (score 0):

You could have ***the inside scoop***...

From [Merriam-Webster Learner's dictionary](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/scoop):

> the scoop *US, informal* : information about something that is currently important or happening or that is interesting to many people
>     *  Did you talk to him? What's the scoop? *[=what did he say?; what is happening?]*
>      * (...)
>     *  I was with them when it happened, so I've got **the inside scoop.** [=information known only by a particular group of people]

also, from [LearnEnglishNow](http://www.learnenglishnow.com/inside_scoop.html):

> What does "inside scoop" mean?
>
> *Definition*: to be knowledgeable; know something most people don't

and [Longman's Dictionary of Contemporary English](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/scoop_1) says:

> 4  *American English   informal*:  information about something:
>   *the **inside scoop*** (=special information that other people do not have) *on the markets*